# Google glass closing second level activity closes app

Tags: android, google-glass

I have two activities, Main Activity and List Activity. I always want a menu displayed on Main Activity as there's no where else to go.

Main Activity has this code:

```
@Override
public void onOptionsMenuClosed(Menu menu) {
    // Nothing else to do, closing the activity.
    finish();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    openOptionsMenu();
}
```

When I close List Activity, my entire app closes - and its due to the onOptionsMenuClosed method in my MainActivity, really confused as to why this is the case, when ListActivity is closed I just want to go back to the menu.

Comment: I see that you post is from 19 March. Did you find the solution for this? I encountered the same problem. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it like this:

```
public class StartActivity extends Activity{
private boolean cancel = true;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    openOptionsMenu();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.startmenu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.Item1){
        cancel  = false;
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        return true;
    }
    else if(id == R.id.Item2){
        cancel = false;
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            openOptionsMenu();
            cancel = true;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onOptionsMenuClosed(Menu menu)
{
  super.onOptionsMenuClosed(menu);
  if(cancel){
      finish();
  }
}
```

}